# Problems logging into SharePoint using Firefox - even with ntml set

Tags: login, firefox

I'm struggling to log in to SharePoint using FireFox. On entering the URL I get prompted with username and password, but when entering these the logon dialog keeps popping up and the page is not loaded.

The scenario is this: I have three web applications running. All of them have the same settings and runs on port 80.

```
Name                                    URL                     Port
intranetttest Currently Selected        http: //intranetttest/  80
MySite                                  http: //minside/        80
SharePoint - 80                         http: //sp/             80
SharePoint Central Administration v4    http: //sp:42424/       42424
```

In one out of three, I'm able to log in and browse the page. This one share the "base" URL with the central admin. The other two, I'm unable to log into using FireFox. IE and Opera works fine.

General settings, managed features, managed paths, service connections, auth providers, self-service site creations, user permissions, webpart security, user policy, anonymous policy and permission policy are all the same - as far as I can see.

I clearly seem to be missing something. Anyone had a similar problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you disable the dreaded "loopback check" ?
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861

You can fire fiddler and launch FF afterward to check which ressource is triggering the credential (first request == IIS issue, a sub request = content issue).

Comment: I would try this too, however strange that it works on some browsers...

Comment: Anything else than IE is less prone to automatically login user using NTML than itself (IE).

Answer (score 1):

An additional setting should be changed as well.

network.auth.force-generic-ntlm should be set to true.

network.auth.force-generic-ntlm | user set | boolean | true